# How to remove lines in a 3 way table that have zero cases

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a table that removes lines that have no cases on them.

```
Data <- data.frame(
group = sample(letters[1:8], 500, replace = TRUE),
center = sample(c("CenterA", "CenterB", "CenterC", "CenterD", "CenterE"), 500, replace = TRUE), 
color  = sample(c("white", "black", "red", "blue", "yellow", "green"), 500, replace = TRUE)
```

Now, I'll generate a lot of empty lines

```
Data$group[Data$group %in% c('b', 'c') & Data$color !='white'] <-"a"
Data$group[Data$group %in% c( 'd', 'e')& Data$color !='black'] <-"f"
Data$group[Data$group=='d' & Data$color !='red'] <-"c"
Data$group[Data$group=='e' & Data$color !='blue'] <-"d"
Data$group[Data$group=='f' & Data$color !='yellow'] <-"e"
Data$group[Data$group=='g' & Data$color !='white'] <-"f"
Data$group[Data$group=='h' & Data$color !='black'] <-"g"
Data$group[Data$group=='a' & Data$color !='red'] <-"h"
```

Now the table

```
with(Data,  table(color, center,group))
```

This table shows a lot of empty lines. Also tried, and didn't work

```
xtabs(~color+center+group, data=Data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

A table with the expected outcome should be like this

```
, , group = a

    center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  red         12      31       7      15      21


, , group = b

    center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  white        9       9      10      10       7


, , group = c

    center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  black        2       4       1       2       3
  white        3       1       4       3       1

, , group = d

        center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  black        7       2       4       0       1

, , group = e

        center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  blue         5       7       4       4       4
  red          3       7       6       4       7

, , group = f

        center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  blue         8       4       6       4       6
  yellow      13      11       9      16       9

, , group = g

        center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  blue         6       5       5       3       8
  white       10       7       5       4       6
  yellow       4       5       9       3       7

, , group = h

        center
color    CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  black       11       7      16      15      17
  blue         4       2       5       2      10
  yellow       3       2       7       4       2
```

The best outcome would be combining it with `prop.table()` or a table that has percentages

```
 with(Data,  prop.table(table(color, center,group),1)
```

It has taken me longer to what I expected, and I tried to create it using dplyr, xtables, aggregate, count, among others. I am aware that probably there are similar questions but I was not able to find any answer after several searches.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `tidyverse`. Though the result will be a list containing a `tibble` for each `group` rather than a table.

```
library(tidyverse)
tab <- Data %>% 
 group_by(group, center, color) %>% 
 summarise(n = n()) %>% 
 # group_by(group) %>% 
 group_by(group, color) %>% # EDIT
 mutate(prop = n / sum(n, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
 select(-n) %>% 
 spread(center, prop) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 split(.$group)
```

Result of the third entry looks like this.

```
tab[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  group  color  CenterA CenterB CenterC CenterD CenterE
  <fctr> <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 c      black   0.0909  NA       0.364   0.273   0.273
2 c      white   0.200    0.200   0.200   0.100   0.300
```

*(Note that the values per row may not be exactly one due to rounding errors.)*

To get the absolute values the code is as follows

```
Data %>% 
 group_by(group, center, color) %>% 
 summarise(n = n()) %>% 
 spread(center, n) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 split(.$group)
```

Comment: That was a fast reply, Thanks a lot. Is there a way to have the proportion for every line?  in this case, the sum for every 'color' should give 1. It's clear I made a mistake when explaining. Again, thanks